# How can I run multiple independent and unrelated functions in parallel without larger code do-over?

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I've been searching around the internet, trying to understand parallel processing.

What they all seem to assume is that I have some kind of loop function operating on e.g. every Nth row of a data set divided among N cores and combined afterwards, and I'm pointed towards a lot of parallelized `apply()` functions.

*(Warning, ugly code below)*

My situation though is that I have is on form

```
tempJob <- myFunction(filepath, string.arg1, string.arg2)
```

where the path is a file location, and the string arguments are various ways of sorting my data.

My current workflow is simply amassing a lot of

```
tempjob1 <- myFunction(args)
tempjob2 <- myFunction(other args)
...
tempjobN <- myFunction(some other args here)

# Make a list of all temporary outputs in the global environment
temp.list <- lapply(ls(pattern = "temp"), get)

# Stack them all
df <- rbindlist(temp.list)

# Remove all variables from workspace matching "temp"
rm(list=ls(pattern="temp"))
```

These jobs are entirely independent, and could in principle be run in 8 separate instances of R (although that would be a bother to manage I guess). How can I separate the first 8 jobs out to 8 cores, and whenever a core finishes its job and returns a treated dataset to the global environment it'll simply take whichever job is next in line.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With the [future](https://cran.r-project.org/package=future) package (I'm the author) you can achieve what you want with a minor modification to your code - use "future" assignments `%<-%` instead of regular assignments `<-` for the code you want to run asynchronously.

```
library("future")
plan(multisession)

tempjob1 %<-% myFunction(args)
tempjob2 %<-% myFunction(other args)
...
tempjobN %<-% myFunction(some other args here)

temp.list <- lapply(ls(pattern = "temp"), get)
```

EDIT 2022-01-04: `plan(multiprocess)` -> `plan(multisession)` since `multiprocess` is deprecated and will eventually be removed.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant, and extremely easy to use! One question: is forking supposed to spawn several R sessions?

I've also found that I need to include `gc()` at the end of my functions when parallelizing them with `%<-%` to prevent my RAM usage from exploding.

Comment: First, `multiprocess` == `multicore` (forked processes) iff supported (i.e. non-Windows), otherwise == `multisession` (spawned background R sessions). Second, `plan(multiprocess)` defaults to `plan(multiprocess, workers = availableCores())`, i.e. uses that number of cores.  Thus, you'll see that many child/background R processes.  You can force close them by changing plan, e.g. `plan(sequential)`, otherwise they'll be closed at end of session.

Comment: Yes, right now you'll have to rely on R to do garbage collection when it thinks it's needed or call `gc()` manually - just as it works in single-core sessions.  I've thought about adding an argument for doing this at the end of the future expression or an option for doing it automatically, but it's probably better to let the developer be explicit about it by manually adding a `gc()` where s/he thinks it best fits.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are unfortunate enough to be using Windows, you could maybe try with **GNU Parallel** like this:

```
parallel Rscript ::: script1.R script2.R JOB86*.R
```

and that would keep 8 scripts running at a time, if your CPU has 8 cores. You can change it with `-j 4` if you just want 4 at a time. The `JOB86` part is just random - I made it up.

You can also add switches for a progress bar, for how to handle errors, for adding parameters and distributing jobs across multiple machines.

If you are on a Mac, you can install **GNU Parallel** with **homebrew**:

```
brew install parallel
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to use one of the parallelized `apply` functions. Those will do all the fiddly work of separating out the jobs, taking whichever job is next in line, etc.

Put all your arguments into a list:

```
args <- list(
    list(filePath1, stringArgs11, stringArgs21),
    list(filePath2, stringArgs12, stringArgs22),
    ...
    list(filePath8, stringArgs18, stringArgs28)
)
```

Then do something like

```
library(parallel)
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores())
df <- parSapply(cl, args, myFunction)
```

I'm not sure about `parSapply`, and I can't check as R isn't working on my machine just now. If that doesn't work, use `parLapply` and then manipulate the result.